# iMacros: "ONDOWNLOAD FILE=mention.jpg" doesn't change the file name

Tags: imacros

I have this macro:

```
VERSION BUILD=8890130 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:icon-bwdownload<SP>componentHeader--icon&&TXT:
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=mention.jpg WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Excel
```

The file is downloaded without problem, but the script should change the file name. However, the name is not changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place your line `ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=mention.jpg WAIT=YES` before the line `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:icon-bwdownload<SP>componentHeader--icon&&TXT:`.

Comment: ONDOWNLOAD command was used but no download occurred. (Error code: -804)

Comment: And file not downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not change the file name. Never!

```
VERSION BUILD=8890130 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:icon-bwdownload<SP>componentHeader--icon&&TXT:
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=mention.jpg WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Excel
```

This will.

```
VERSION BUILD=8890130 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:icon-bwdownload<SP>componentHeader--icon&&TXT:
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+{{!NOW:yymmdd}}mention.jpg WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Excel
```

Comment: Doesn't Work :( File is downloaded with original name, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In version 10.3 and previous ones, you were only allowed to ADD something to the file name:

"Normally the download file name is created automatically by the website. You can add parts to the original file name by using the + syntax (see Examples). The built-in variable !NOW is helpful in this context."

From subsequent versions you should be able to change the whole name.